# Laravel 5.5 - No migrations found

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, database-migration

I want to use *jeremykenedy/laravel-roles*. When I type:

```
$ php artisan migrate:status
```

There is shows: **No migrations found**.
I have migrations in *database/migrations*.

How to fix it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you have to ```php artisan vendor:publish```

Comment: I have migrations in database/migrations

Comment: php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravelroles

Answer (score 2):

Firstly install migration so use this command

```
php artisan migrate:install
```

and then use this command

```
php artisan migrate:status
```

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue recently after adding a config/database.php file.

This file returns an array with database connection settings but also has a key that defines the migrations table.  If you do not have that definition Laravel will not know where to look for migrations.

```
<?php

return [
  connections: [
    // ...
  ],
  'migrations' => 'migrations' /* <-- make sure you have this line */
];
```

When you do not have the file it looks in the migrations table by default.

An example of the config file can be found here
https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/database.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to first publish the assets to your project with:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravelroles
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, below steps did the trick.

```
composer install

php artisan migrate
```